# How can I model tape with imperfections?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, cloth-simulation

[image]
I am trying to create stand-alone tape pieces with these sorts of imperfections. The way sometimes tape collapses on itself and creates ridges and overlaps.
I have tried to achieve the look desired by Pining a vertex group under the shape tab of the cloth physics panel. But the results are not what I want. The ridges are very harsh, as in they stop and start abruptly, not like a gradual descent seen in Top Left Tape piece in the reference. I tried to solve this by subdividing the plane many times but that didn't help too.

Comment: Try going into sculpt mode and using the Cloth Brush

Comment: Tried that, didn't quite get the overlaps and folding over itself nature of a sticky tape (pic ref: last row middle one). Do you have some advice/suggestions for that?

Comment: someday, you'll regret the login name "BlenderBeginner" :-)